# Using cfn-lint in nested stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When using cfn-lint in nested stacks, it seems that the parameters of the root stack are not passed over to the child stack, so the check doesn't work properly.

cfn-lint will not find any errors if you enter the wrong parameters in the ROOT stack.

root stack

```
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: dir/child.yml
      Parameters:
```

If you put the S3 path in the templateURL, it will not be checked,
Local path returns error W3002.

This stack deploys normally.

Can you help me ?